# Semi-Colon placed before opening bracket in a while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, syntax

```
while(condition);{ 
    statement;
}
```

The semi-colon before the opening bracket of the while loop shouldn't be there. The question I'm having is why the program gets stuck at the while loop during run time. As far as I'm aware the semi-colon is a terminating punctuator that lets the compiler know that it has come to the end of the statement. Since it doesn't read the opening bracket of the while loop shouldn't it then move on to the next line and perform the action? If you run the debugger and move step by step, it stops moving at the while statement and will not go further. I'm just looking for some insight as to why this is the case. If it is the case that the while has to be followed by a condition and then the opening bracket why does it compile when the semi-colon is placed in between? Shouldn't some sort of error be thrown?

The IDE being used is Dev c++. I'm not sure if this is a IDE specific issue as I've not tested this in other IDEs.

Comment: This:  while(condition); gets interpreted as an empty block after the condition, so you end up with a loop doing nothing.

Comment: Reminds me of my naughty friend who put O in place of 0 to confuse my computer teacher for hours end

Comment: `while (condition);` can also be written `while (condition) { }`, which I find more obvious.  You have `while (condition) { /* infinite loop */ } { ... /* unreachable code */}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rewrite your code using a better formatting, which probably would make the problem clearer to you:

```
while(condition)
  ;

{ 
    statement;
}
```

If `condition` is true (i.e. non-0), you iterate an infinite loop.

If `condition` is false (i.e. 0), execution moves forward to the following statement.

Comment: AH. I missed checking on the whether the condition was true or not. Of course it was true which is why we were in an infinite loop. This makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The definition of a while loop is

```
while(condition) statement;
```

So when you use a while loop it will only execute `statement`.  Since you statement is empty (`while(condition);`), nothing is executed and the loop, loops again.  This will go on forever.

When you write something like

```
while (something)
{
    //more stuff
    //even more stuff
    //and something else
}
```

The whole `{}` block is treated as the single statement.

Comment: This also answers "why does it compile when the semi-colon is placed in between?"

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I'm aware the semi colon is a terminating punctuator that lets the compiler know that it has come to the end of the statement.

The role of `;` in C++ grammar is not that simplistic and straightforward. Actually, many (if not most) statements in C++ do not have `;` at the end. It is simply not necessary for the compiler to detect the end of the statement.

Among iteration statements, only `do`  statement ends with a `;`. Other iteration statements do not end with a `;`. This means that whatever `;` you see in `for` or `while` iteration statements actually belong to "nested" statements in the body of the loop.

In your case

```
while (condition);
```

is just a `while` loop, whose body consists of a mere `;`. This lone `;` does not directly belong to the `while` statement. This lone `;` actually belongs to an empty statement, which constitutes the body of your loop. In other words your cycle is interpreted as

```
while (condition) 
  /* Empty statement */;
```

So, in your case the loop just keeps executing that empty statement indefinitely.

The opening bracket and the rest of your code is seen as an independent compound statement, which has nothing to do with your loop.